# Java Timestamp to MySQL Timestamp

Tags: java, mysql, timestamp

I have this code, but it is not working. I have Error message:

"com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'Datum_zalozeni' at row 1"

```
  pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(INSERT);
                Timestamp ts = u.getDatum_zalozeni();
                System.out.println(ts);
                pstmt.setTimestamp(1, ts);
                pstmt.setInt(2, u.getId_klient());
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

My database is:

```
CREATE TABLE Ucet
(
  Id_Uctu Int NOT NULL auto_increment primary key,
  Datum_zalozeni Timestamp NOT NULL,
  Id_klient Int NOT NULL
)
;
```

Where is mistake? I think code is correct.

Comment: Can you please post the value in the 'INSERT' variable ?

Comment: private static String INSERT = "insert into Ucet values (null,?,?)";  When you insert a time stamp manually, it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a code to generate the System Timestamp. It sets 0 in place of 979. Have a look.

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class TimestampTest
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("System Date: " + generateTimestamp("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Timestamp generateTimestamp(String format)
{
    Timestamp timestamp = null;

    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

        Date date = dateFormat.parse(generateDate(format));

        timestamp = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return timestamp;
}

public static String generateDate(String format)
{
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

    return (dateFormat.format(date));
}
}
```

Comment: It is working. Thank you so much. But i dont know, why it did not worked, because i use manualy: "INSERT INTO ucetnidb.Ucet values(null,'2015-03-31 14:24:25.979',1);" and this is work.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL usually accepts Timestamps in the format '2013-12-06 14:24:34'. It would be helpful if you share what is the exact value you are trying to insert into the database.

```
Timestamp ts = u.getDatum_zalozeni();
System.out.println(ts);
pstmt.setTimestamp(1, ts);
```

What is ts?

Comment: This is ts: 2015-04-25 16:17:22.979

Comment: Can we remove 979 from the ts and keep it to 2015-04-25 16:17:22? I am saying cause its a MysqlDataTruncation error

Comment: but how can i remowe 979? This is timestamp format.